# Chrome or Firefox fails to start on selenium node machine if the node is started from a shell script at the startup

Tags: linux, selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid2

I have a shell script to register the node machine to hub at startup.

The script contains:

java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server.jar -role node -hub http://HUB_IP:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="firefox",maxInstances=5,Platform="LINUX",applicationName="VM_NAME" -browser browserName="chrome",maxInstances=5,Platform="LINUX",applicationName="VM_NAME" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=~/selenium/chromedriver

The script starts fine in the startup and even the node gets registered to hub, but, when I start a job from Jenkins its gives below error in case of Firefox:

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified

When I start a job from Jenkins its gives below error in case of Chrome:

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setup
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Note:
1. Using later version of chrome, firefox & Selenium jar files
2. When the script is run manually, everything works fine.
3. Start up batch file in windows works fine without any problem.

Comment: are you using the same user to start the node and to execute the script at startup?

Comment: @BorisStoyanov, yes the same user is starting the process at start up... the script is called from rc.local with the below command

su - username -c '/path/to/script/script.sh &'